# Does SQLite have an equivalent to TO_CHAR?

Tags: sqlite

With Oracle I can format a number as text using to_char:

```
select to_char(12345, '999,990.00') from dual
```

which returns `12,345.00`

How can I do the same using SQLite?
I made some attempts using the `printf` function, but met with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add thousand marks to integers with `%,d`, and output two decimal places for floating-point numbers with `%.2d`, but it is not possible to combine them.

In general, you should format values in your application.

Comment: For reference: https://www3.sqlite.org/printf.html